# Accessing "THIS" variable outside of string

Tags: php

I have adapted a shopping cart program which builds a series of items based on POSTED form data and combines that data to form the shopping cart. Each item is given a line in the cart using the $this command:

```
foreach($this->get_contents() as $item) {

echo tab(7) . "<input type='hidden' id='jcartItempartnumber-{$item['id']}' 
          name='jcartItempartnumber[]' value='{$item['partnumber']}' />
          Part Number: {$item['partnumber']} \n";
          }
```

So each line item accepts and removes the Part Numbers without issue. The issue becomes That I can't put these part numbers down in the footer of the cart itself with the subtotal.

```
echo tab(7) . "<span id='jcart-subtotal'>Cost: <strong>$currencySymbol" . 
number_format($this->subtotal, $priceFormat['decimals'],     $priceFormat['dec_point'], 
$priceFormat['thousands_sep']) . "</strong></span>\n";
```

Is there an easy way to display the unique part numbers down below? How do I reference a $this variable outside of the $this string?

***----EDIT----***
Item 1 has several values.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="Instrumentation Enclosure" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-partnumber" value="In" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" />
```

For each cart option there is only a few values
for any item with an item ID of '2' there are only two possibilities; "R" and "In"
I just want to create a variable which echo's either R or In when the ID=2

Comment: `$this` has nothing to do with strings. `$this` is a "pointer" to the object you're currently in. if you want to use an in-object value somewhere OUTSIDE of the object, you'd have to store it somewhere, like `$var = $this->valueyouwant`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This was my understanding as well, HOWEVER my problem happens when I come to store these values, if I set these values as a single variable, they end up writing over one another and the end result is that only the last stored value is remembered. Is there a way to store the variable based on multiple values? i.e. $var.(this -> id) = $this -> itempartnumber so that the object creates a variable NAME based on id# and then the content of that variable is the partnumber?

Comment: that's the wrong way of thinking about it. you don't want to create on-the-fly variable names. now you've expanded the problem to "how to do I tell everything else what this new variable name is?".

Comment: in other words, you have a fundamental design/planning problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: So what this is is a way to build up a product by selecting different options akin to a computer, so telling everything else what the new variable numbers are will be minimal. Made an edit above to explain better.